# USB Type C monitor compatible with a pre type-c laptop

Tags: usb, display, power-supply

My setup includes two laptops. A MacBook Pro from work which is the newest model and my private Dell XPS 13 from 2014.

I'm currently buying a new monitor and decided on this one: [Dell S2718D](http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-27-ultrathin-monitor-s2718d/apd/210-alwd/monitors-monitor-accessories).

> **Features**
>
> USB 3.1 hub
>
> (...)
>
> **Interfaces**
>
> 1 x HDMI / 1 x USB Type C (Alternate mode with DP 1.2, USB 3.1
>   upstream port, Power Delivery PD up to 45W) / 1 x Analog 2.0 audio
>   line out (3.5 mm jack) / 2 X USB 3

This is of course absolutely neat if used with the newer MacBook, since it already features USB type C. I just need to connect one single cable and the video-signal, power-supply and USB hub works.

What I can't get my head around is my older Dell XPS. Commonly I needed to connect three cables to it: the video-signal (mDP Laptop to DP monitor), the USB hub (USB port on my laptop to an usb port type B on the monitor) and of course the power supply of the laptop itself.

[image: diagram]

How can I use it with this new kind of type-c monitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Type c is just the form of the plug. It does not tell you what it uses or what is compatible with it.

Most of the time a type-C plug is used for:

- Thunderbolt-3 (PCI-e part)
- Thunderbolt-3 (the multiplexed displayport part)
- USB 3.1 gen 2 (USB, usually the newest standard on the newest plug)
- USB 3.1 gen 1 (USB, often via an Intel chip which can do both thundebolt-3 and USB and detects what you use).

But nothing stops a manufacturer from putting only hi-speed USB 1 (1.5mbit/sec) on a type-C port.

With that out of the way your post mentions:

1. `USB 3.1 hub`. So it probably can do the same as classic USB 3 (also known as USB 3.1 gen 1). A simply cable or passive convertor plug will work to enable the USB hub part.
2. `Interfaces: 1 x HDMI / 1 x USB Type C (Alternate mode with DP 1.2 ...`
    Now that seems to indicate that it not just supports the fall back to old USB 3, but it also supports displayport on the cable. That is not the same as USB and you will not get an image with just a USB port and a dongle to physically convert to the -C form factor'
3. `Power Delivery PD up to 45W`.
   I'll mostly skip this, but with the right modern device and a correct cable you can use this to charge a device. E.g. connect a macbook to a monitor, output graphics to a DP port monitor while at the same time charging the laptop. There is much more to it though.

Comment: Okay, let me get this straight. The MacBook just fits in neatly, right? It just has one usb-cable to the monitor and everything is fine, right? The XPS on the other hand needs to be connected just like it was "back in the days" (power supply, video signal cable, usb cable). The only difference is that the USB connector is type A in the laptop and type C in the monitor in comparsion to the past where it was still type A in the laptop but mostly type B in the monitor, right?

Comment: I am not up to date on Macbooks, but generally yes. They are on the front of some developements, including displayport and charging over USB-C.

Answer (score 0):

Despite your specific monitor does not need this, I will address the more generic question posed in the title: how do we connect a monitor which only has a USB C input to a host which only has a DisplayPort output (or even worse, HDMI only)?

The answer lies in *bidirectional* USB C - DisplayPort cables and also special adapters made for this case. Here's a non-exhaustive list:

1. AmazonBasics UTC-DP-B-L
2. Club 3D CAC-1557
3. Infinnet cables (EAN 0701948284759, 0701948284728)
4. Moshi 99MO084102

Special adapters include the simple DeLock DP -> USB-C adapter 63928 and then two devices both of which combine USB and a display signal into USB C:

1. Belkin VR cable (input: DisplayPort male + two USB A males, output: USB C male)
2. Wacom Link adapter ACK42719 (DisplayPort/HDMI/USB input, USB C output, all female)